# p:dataTable, lazy loading and global filter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using lazy loading ,paging and global filter in the dataTable

In the lazy load function I add 2 function in order to support 2 scenarios:

1) When the user is paging

2) When the user add a value in the global filter and press "Enter"

Basically what I need to know is what activity was execute in order to decide what function to use.

dataTable:

```
     <p:dataTable id="osTable"       
                     var="object"
                     value="#{bean.lazyModel}"
                     selection="#{bean.selectedObjectSet}"
                     selectionMode="single"
                     rowKey="#{object.ID}"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                     paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                     rows="10"
                     widgetVar="objectTable">
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <p:outputPanel style="float: right"> 
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" /> 
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                                 onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {objectSetTable.filter()}"
                                 style="width:150px"/>
                </p:outputPanel> 
            </f:facet>
```

load function:

```
  @Override
public List<CfgSe2deMapping> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
    List<Mapping> data = new ArrayList<Mapping>();


    if (// if user press enter ) {
        data.addAll(MappingHelper.getViaFilter(filters.get("globalFilter")));
    } else {
        data.addAll(MappingHelper.getViaOffSet(first + 1, first + pageSize));
    }
```

I am using primefaces 3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are thinking this the wrong way. no matter what the user did, you should always do the same: retrieve data (applying filters, if any) and paginate (return `pageSize` rows starting from `first`.

why aren't you including the 'first' and 'pageSize' parameters when there's a filter? rows have to be paginated either way. otherwise the user would be able to see only the first page of filtered results.

Also, you have to override getRowCount method, so that your table shows the right number of pages.

Comment: Regarding the getRowCount I am initialize it in the Lazy constructor.

Comment: my solution is in the load function i am checking if isPaginationRequest && !filters.isEmpty() ,what do you think ?

Comment: @angus why do you need to know whether is a pagination request or if a filter changed? even if you are filtering you have to paginate.. the filtered results may not fit in one single page. therefore you have to combine your 2 methods (getViaFilter and getViaOffset).